# Find the tangent line for the following: $(\operatorname{arcsec} x)^2$ at $x = 2$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, hyperbolic-functions, tangent-line

I have been doing a lot of tangent line problems and they follow a pretty basic pattern. Plug in $x$ to find the $y$ value. Find the derivative and the slope and then $b$. However, with these hyperbolic functions, my work is looking really messy and I am unsure how to find the $y$ value. I want to be able to do this without a calculator. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Could you include some of the work you've done so far?

Comment: What hyperbolic function?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I don’t have time to put my work into text.

Hope it is clear enough.[image]

At $x=2$, the positive value should be taken.

Comment: Wolfram agrees.